# Geometric proof for derivative of $f(x)=\sqrt{x}$

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Using a square of  area $x$,

we obtain

$$dx = (2\sqrt{x})d\sqrt{x}+(d\sqrt{x})^2$$
$$\frac{d\sqrt{x}}{dx} = \frac{1}{2 \sqrt{x}} - \frac{(d\sqrt{x})^2}{2\sqrt{x}dx}$$

How do I show that $\frac{(d\sqrt{x})^2}{2\sqrt{x}dx} \rightarrow 0$ as $dx\rightarrow0$?

Comment: It's because the numerator of $\frac{(d\sqrt{x})^2}{2\sqrt{x}dx}$ is a second order infinitesimal compared to the denominator which is a first order infinitesimal (all this being in the way people where thinking at the birth of infinitesimal calculus).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

\begin{eqnarray}
\Delta x &=& (2\sqrt{x})\Delta\sqrt{x}+(\Delta\sqrt{x})^2\\
\Delta x&=&(2\sqrt{x}+\Delta\sqrt{x})\Delta\sqrt{x}\\
(2\sqrt{x}+\Delta\sqrt{x})\Delta\sqrt{x}&=&\Delta x\\
\frac{\Delta\sqrt{x}}{\Delta x}&=&\frac{1}{2\sqrt{x}+\Delta\sqrt{x}}
\end{eqnarray}

As $\Delta x\to0$, then $\Delta\sqrt{x}\to0$.

So, as $\Delta x\to0$ we have
$$ \frac{d}{dx}\sqrt{x}=\frac{1}{2\sqrt{x}} $$

Answer (score 1):

By your geometric construction, and also by your first line, when $dx \rightarrow 0$, $d\sqrt x \rightarrow 0$.

$\frac {dx} {d\sqrt x} = 2\sqrt x + d\sqrt x$
So when $dx \rightarrow 0, \frac {dx} {d\sqrt x} \rightarrow 2\sqrt x$

So when $x\ne 0, \frac {(d\sqrt x)^2} {2\sqrt x dx}$ is equivalent when $dx \rightarrow 0$ to $\frac {d\sqrt x} {4x}$.
When $dx\rightarrow 0$, this $\rightarrow 0$.